# How to pair Hidden Radio Bluetooth Speakers?

Tags: bluetooth

I have a [Hidden Radio Bluetooth Speaker](http://www.hiddenradiodesign.com/), it has worked flawlessly with Mac OS X, but now that I'm trying with Ubuntu, I get stuck at the "pass key" step, no matter which option I try (random, custom, without pairing), it just says set up of new device failed.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have many problems connecting with Ubuntu 12.04 64 Bit.

I clicked on the Bluetooth icon in the corner (The little 'B").

Then I clicked on "Set Up New Device".

That opened the Bluetooth New Device Setup.  Press Continue.  It will scan for devices.

Automatic PIN detection did not work, but I clicked on "PIN options..." and selected '0000' (most headsets, etc).

Then I clicked Continue and it connected.

To get sound to output, I cliked again on the Blutooth 'B' and under "Devices" I hovered on HiddenRadio, and went to "Sound Settings".

On the settings page, Clikc on Hidden Radio, and sound will come from the Hidden Radio.

Comment: An image would be appropriate to explain your answer, Though not mandatory.